# Received "This post was deleted" message when trying to edit a review audit

Tags: bug, review, review-audits

I was going through the review process on SO when I encountered a poor quality answer that seemed like an OK-ish answer, but needed some spit and polish to aid interpretation.

Clicked "edit" and the message stated "this post has been deleted", which is fine, but then I come back to the review page and it's either "no action needed" or "skip", neither of which make sense if it's been deleted.  I choose to downvote it and then place a comment as to why I downvoted in order to unlock the "I'm done" button, but I immediately received the "you passed the test" message.

In my opinion, this is not how the system should work. When I clicked "edit", I should have received the "you passed the test" notification. Or, when I was notified that the post had been deleted, I should have been passed automatically to the next item to review, or the "there are no items left to review" message.

Comment: Er. Yeah, I wouldn't have tried to downvote it, since you shouldn't be able to downvote deleted posts. I would've said "no action needed" and apparently failed

Comment: If I shouldn't be able to downvote deleted posts, it shouldn't have a down arrow.

Comment: I would concur that this duplicates the other, though I think this one is worded better.  Might be biased.  :-)  Do note, I did try to search for duplicates before opening this.

Comment: I think the answer on the "original of which this is a duplicate" is not satisfactory.  This is a bug which requires resolution.  The answer on the "original" is actually a variation of the solution proposed in the above question, but is not implemented or otherwise.  Requested re-open.